# IE8 -- Asynchronous Validation of JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, internet-explorer-8, race-condition

So I'm seeing some strange issues in ie8 with jquery, and assorted javascript files. These errors are not occurring in Firefox, Safari, or previous versions of IE. The main thing that's happening are variable undefined, mismatched bracket errors, etc... but the error changes each time you force-refresh the page. Checking the cited files reveals no such syntactical errors.

My question is, first, has anyone else seen such errors? It seems similar to issues with asynchronous events. Does this have something to do with the new multi-process/multi-threaded browsing features in IE8? Does IE 8 perform some sort of validation on js files immediately after they've been downloaded?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: Looks like it's shuffling elements of received js files into a larger js file. In the debugger it's showing a method from one file, right in the middle of code from another file. The code that the "imported" segment relies on is not to be found. Not sure what's happening here....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, turns out it's an issue with specifying a mime type of 'application/javascript' instead of 'text/javascript'. Application makes ie8 go crazy....and to think we used application in the first place to get around previous ie version bugs.